# Add empty overlay to leaflet map?

Tags: angularjs, leaflet

Looking for a way to add an empty overlay to a `Leaflet` map. I have multiple `Leaflet` overlays that load in their data from a realtime server. Because I am using a custom UI control and not the default `Leaflet` one, I have a listener that every time new markers are created, checks to see whether their associated layer is `active`, and if it is, adds the markers to that layer.

```
$rootScope.on('newMarkers',markers)->
  type = *fn to find type*
  if mapFactory.currentLayers[type]?.active
     mapFactory.addLayer(markers, type)
)
```

I don't think building in logic to see whether it's the *first* time a marker is being added to that layer makes sense, and would rather create an empty layer and add data to it after. I know you can do this with the `L.geoJson` type, but this layer is made entirely of plain `markers`. Any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `L.LayerGroup`for this:

> Used to group several layers and handle them as one. If you add it to the map, any layers added or removed from the group will be added/removed on the map as well. Implements ILayer interface.

Reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup

Or `L.FeatureGroup`:

> Extended layerGroup that also has mouse events (propagated from members of the group) and a shared bindPopup method. Implements ILayer interface.

Reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup